# CSS/HTML: why don't these line up?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a basic template out of a design I put together in photoshop but am having difficulty.  Can anyone explain why these don't line up?

http://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=8wN5QxamaU

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kShp.png

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="column-center"></div>
    <div class="column-left"></div>
    <div class="column-right"><img src="castle1.png"></div>
    <div class="column-center-top"><img src="top.png"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
background-image: url('0x0E14.bmp');
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 774px;
    line-height: 0;
}
.column-left{ float: left; width: 416px; height: 154px; line-height: 0; display: table-cell; background-image: url('topscroll.png');}
.column-left2{ display: inline-block; width: 100%; line-height: 0; }
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; line-height: 0; }
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; line-height: 0; }
.column-center-top{ display: inline-block; line-height: 0; background-image: url('top.png');}
.column-center-body{ line-height: 0; background-image: url('containerbg.png');}

.menu { 
margin: auto;
line-height: 0;
height: 54px; 
width: 748px; 
display: table-cell; 
vertical-align: middle; 
text-align: center; 
background-image: url('menu.png');
}
```

Comment: sweet UO graphics. Is the PNG the desired result?

Comment: @BrandtSolovij hehe.  no, it should look like this:  http://i.imgur.com/21U8fup.png

Comment: can you set this up in a cssbin or similar?

Comment: @wazz sure, here you go: http://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=8wN5QxamaU